# Error: cannot find symbol - Java compile error

Tags: java, int, symbols

I've been looking at this for a while now, and I'm sure the fix is right in front of me but I'm just blind to it. Someone care to point out why my int i is giving me an error?

CacheDownloader class:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String strFilePath = "./version.txt";
    try
    {
      FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(strFilePath);
     DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(fin);
     int i = din.readInt();
       System.out.println("int : " + i);
       din.close();
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException fe)
    {
      System.out.println("FileNotFoundException : " + fe);
    }
    catch(IOException ioe)
    {
      System.out.println("IOException : " + ioe);
    }
  }

    private final int VERSION = i;
```

Error:

```
CacheDownloader.java:54: error: cannot find symbol
        private final int VERSION = i;
                                    ^
  symbol:   variable i
  location: class CacheDownloader
```

Comment: which int, what is the exact line?

Comment: Last line there is the error, cannot find symbol for "i"

Comment: What is the error? Also what can you comment out without the error going away?

Comment: `int i` is local to `try` block, and you trying to refer it outside the `try/catch` block, why ???? Obviously it is bound to raise concerns :-) Please look into declaring and initializing variable `i` at the start of `main` method, in this case. Not related though, but stop using `main` method to perform tasks, instead delegate this responsibility to some another method, just use `main` to start the application and nothing else.

Comment: `i` is not visible outside of your main method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i is declared in main, private final int VERSION is outside of main. Move it inside main or declare i as a global.

```
static int i=0;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String strFilePath = "./version.txt";
    try
    {
      FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(strFilePath);
      DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(fin);
      i = din.readInt();
      System.out.println("int : " + i);
      din.close();
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException fe)
    {
       System.out.println("FileNotFoundException : " + fe);
    }
    catch(IOException ioe)
    {
       System.out.println("IOException : " + ioe);
    }
}
private final int VERSION = i;
```

Comment: Your variables should be static in order to access them in static scope.

Comment: This fixed my compile error. But now it's reading my version.txt as 0 (zero) even though I have a 9 in it. It was reading it correctly before.

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare your int `i` before the `try-catch` block. Also, you have to declare your constant inside your `main` method:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String strFilePath = "./version.txt";
    int i;
    try
    {
      FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(strFilePath);
      DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(fin);
      i = din.readInt();
      System.out.println("int : " + i);
      din.close();
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException fe)
    {
      System.out.println("FileNotFoundException : " + fe);
    }
    catch(IOException ioe)
    {
      System.out.println("IOException : " + ioe);
    }
    final int VERSION = i; 
  }
```

Comment: You can't specify private inside a method scope.

Comment: @Eranda Yes, you are right. Thanks for correct me! I think now it's in the good way. Correct me if I'm wrong again, I'm learning Java, not a beginner  at all but some concepts are not familiar with me yet. Thank you!